# Xcode throws "No such file or directory" error when trying to run a script in BuildPhases

Tags: ios, xcode

I’m trying to get the Clarifai Apple SDK working following these (https://cocoapods.org/pods/Clarifai-Apple-SDK) steps. I cloned it to a folder on my desktop (I’m just testing right now) and copied the two files using Terminal. Now, after I’ve set up the Run Script Build Phase and try to build my project, it fails with this error:

*"/Users/myUserName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myProjectName-gfnnamzbdltilmbpqnmquaslvvut/Build/Intermediates.noindex/myProjectName.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/myProjectName.build/Script-6BDBB8652003EB2700F153E3.sh: line 2: ~/Desktop/myProjectName/Clarifai/setup_framework.sh: No such file or directory”*

The script is exactly in the location where Xcode claims there is no such file or directory. I followed every step in that guide and I can’t for the life of me figure out what's the issue. Any help in getting this working is greatly appreciated.

Just in case: I'm running Xcode 9.2 on the latest version of High Sierra, which would be 10.13.2, I believe. The project I created is a tabbed application for iOS.

I googled the error already, but the solutions that were offered either did not work or weren't applicable to my situation.

This is my first question on here, so please tell me if I missed anything or something.

There are neither spaces nor special characters in myProjectName.

Comment: What does the run script build phase look like?

Comment: Space in myProjectName?

Comment: @Dare Before it was this: **"~/Desktop/myProjectName/Clarifai/setup_framework.sh"** Since Xcode says you can also drag it in, I did that, which resulted in **/Users/myUserName/Desktop/myProjectName/Clarifai/setup_framework.sh**. This also failed to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution! I basically tried randomly and it was fixed by putting the script into the Input Files of the Build Phase. I don't know why that works without it in Clarifai's documentation, but whatever...